# CURL not working for SOAP enveloped XML request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

I tried to get response from SOAP request using CURL but can't get any success. I got error like,

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I used code,

```
$envelope = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://schemas.tourico.com/webservices/authentication" xmlns:hot="http://tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3" xmlns:hot1="http://schemas.tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <aut:AuthenticationHeader>
         <aut:LoginName>vibXXX</aut:LoginName>
         <aut:Password>111111</aut:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <aut:Culture>en_US</aut:Culture>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <aut:Version>7.123</aut:Version>
      </aut:AuthenticationHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hot:SearchHotels>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hot:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hot1:Destination>NYC</hot1:Destination>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hot1:HotelCityName>New York</hot1:HotelCityName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hot1:HotelLocationName></hot1:HotelLocationName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hot1:HotelName></hot1:HotelName>
            <hot1:CheckIn>2014-02-15</hot1:CheckIn>
            <hot1:CheckOut>2014-02-18</hot1:CheckOut>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hot1:RoomsInformation>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <hot1:RoomInfo>
                  <hot1:AdultNum>2</hot1:AdultNum>
                  <hot1:ChildNum>0</hot1:ChildNum>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <hot1:ChildAges>
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <hot1:ChildAge age="0"/>
                  </hot1:ChildAges>
               </hot1:RoomInfo>
            </hot1:RoomsInformation>
            <hot1:MaxPrice>0</hot1:MaxPrice>
            <hot1:StarLevel>0</hot1:StarLevel>
            <hot1:AvailableOnly>1</hot1:AvailableOnly>
            <hot1:PropertyType>NotSet</hot1:PropertyType>
            <hot1:ExactDestination>1</hot1:ExactDestination>
         </hot:request>
      </hot:SearchHotels>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$soap_do = curl_init();

curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://demo-hotelws.touricoholidays.com/hotelflow.svc?wsdl" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );            
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $envelope); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"http://demo-hotelws.touricoholidays.com/HotelFlow.svc/bas\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($envelope))); 

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
exit;
```

I got response in SOAPUI software but not working with php code.

Can anyone help me to sorted out this problem?

I have also tried with SOAP client. Its also not works I previously ask question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521785/soap-request-for-tourico-webservice-implementation

[image]

Comment: I see SearchHotels is been declared as operation (method) in WSDL. But actually the definition is not available at server. The service needs to update WSDL for the changes.

Comment: No. Its available on server, because i tested it in SOAPUI software. I have attached image in my edited question

Comment: Please check if your CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS datatypes and values are correct. I see CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS needs to be an array http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: I checked it and its perfect, you can pass array and string also

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to find fix... but one thing you can do is use wireshark to see how request is made by looking at packet transfer. Compare packet transfer for SOapUI and php code.

Comment: No Problem. Thank you for giving your valuable time to check this issue.

Comment: Any updates. I having same issue. Did all these things, tried curl after failing soap and ended up here. Please help