# Convert multiple arrays into XML in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, cakephp

This is my array:

```
 Array (
     [Payments] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [Payment] => Array (
                  [Invoice] => Array (
                      [InvoiceNumber] => INV-0084
                  )
                  [Account] => Array (
                      [Code] => 260
                  )
                 [Date] => 1969-12-31T17:00:00
                 [Amount] => 119
             )
         )
        [1] => Array (
            [Payment] => Array (
                 [Invoice] => Array (
                       [InvoiceNumber] => INV-0085
                 )
                 [Account] => Array (
                       [Code] => 260
                 )
                 [Date] => 1969-12-31T17:00:00
                 [Amount] => 132
             )
        )
    )
)
```

I need to convert it to XML data. I have used the CakePHP library to convert the XML data.

```
<Payments>
  <Payment>
     <Invoice>
         <InvoiceNumber>INV-0084</InvoiceNumber>
     </Invoice>
     <Account>
         <Code>260</Code>
     </Account>
     <Date>2016-06-01T17:00:00 </Date>
     <Amount>119</Amount>
 </Payment>
 <Payment>
     <Invoice>
         <InvoiceNumber>INV-0085</InvoiceNumber>
    </Invoice>
    <Account>
       <Code>260</Code>
    </Account>
    <Date>2016-06-01T17:00:00 </Date>
    <Amount>132</Amount>
</Payment>
```

I had used the function

```
$paymentXml = Xml::fromArray($paymentXmlData, array('format' =>'tags'));
$paymentXml = $paymentXml->asXML();
```

The error I got was:

> SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document","file":"/var/www/html/limeactuarial/lib/Cake/Utility/Xml.php","line":197

How do I solve these by using the default library?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428323/convert-multidimensional-array-into-xml

Comment: I like to have the answer using cakephp library

Comment: I can easily convert array without [0] and [1] which you can see in array (i.e)  single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation. Your data is not correctly structured; nodes need to be nested under a single key, which serves as the name for the nodes.

What you are doing there will effectively create multiple root nodes, like:

```
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <Invoice>
            <InvoiceNumber>INV-0084</InvoiceNumber>
        </Invoice>
        ...
    </Payment>
</Payments>
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <Invoice>
            <InvoiceNumber>INV-0085</InvoiceNumber>
        </Invoice>
        ...
    </Payment>
</Payments>
```

Which is invalid XML. Your data needs to be structured like this, where `Payments` will be the root node, containing two `Payment` nodes.

```
array(
    'Payments' => array(
        'Payment' => array(
            array(
                'Invoice' => array(
                    'InvoiceNumber' => 'INV-0084'
                ),
                'Account' => array(
                    'Code' => '260'
                ),
                'Date' => '1969-12-31T17:00:00',
                'Amount' => '119'
            ),
            array(
                'Invoice' => array(
                    'InvoiceNumber' => 'INV-0085'
                ),
                'Account' => array(
                    'Code' => '260'
                ),
                'Date' => '1969-12-31T17:00:00',
                'Amount' => '132'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

See also:

- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Utilities > XML > Transforming an array into a string of XML](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml)**